White background added to all the text on my page (Firefox / Mac)
Does anybody could explain why on my client's laptop, her portfolio looks like that :
(https://i.sstatic.net/L8ZVa4dr.jpg)
But on every other laptop or cellphone (I've tried on another mac with Firefox), it works perfectly and looks like that :
(https://i.sstatic.net/nFutDsPN.jpg)
The code is HTML/CSS/JS with node.js and react. Could it just be a compatibility issue with an old version of her macOS or firefox ?

Without seeing relevant code we cannot help - any answer will just be a guess. Please read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

We need a minimal reproducible example to be sure but my guess is she may have some accessibility settings enabled to show alt text for images and provide high contrast backgrounds for things like links and text over images

I looked into your guess and it was exactly the problem ! Thank you !
